# where is wheel(.whl) file created inside Azure pipeline run?

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines, databricks, pipeline, azure-databricks

I built a simple ymal file for Azure pipeline.
Tasks:

- Build wheel file during Azure pipeline run
- Copy wheel file just created in the pipeline run to databricks' dbfs

It does write .whl file somewhere as I can see in scrip print in the pipeline, but it doesn't overwrite into the repo or I don't know where the file created is?

```
stages:
  - stage: Build
    jobs: 
    - job:
      steps:
      - task: Bash@3
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: | 
            echo 'install/update pip and wheel'
            python -m pip install --upgrade pip wheel 
            echo 'building wheel file'
            python src/databricks/setup.py bdist_wheel
        displayName: 'Build updated wheel file'
  - stage: Deploy
    jobs:
    - job: 
      steps:
      - script: |
          python src/databricks/setup.py bdist_wheel
          echo 'installing databricks-cli'
          python -m pip install --upgrade databricks-cli
        displayName: 'install databricks cli'                    
      - script: |
          echo 'copying wheel file'
          databricks fs cp --overwrite src/databricks/dist/library-0.0.2-py3-none-any.whl dbfs:/FileStore/whl
          echo 'copying main.py'
          databricks fs cp --overwrite src/databricks/main.py dbfs:/FileStore/whl
        env:
          DATABRICKS_HOST: $(DATABRICKS_HOST)
          DATABRICKS_TOKEN: $(DATABRICKS_TOKEN)
        displayName: 'Copy wheel file and main.py to dbfs'
```

Comment: Each `job` runs on a fresh copy of the repository. Nothing is persisted **anywhere** by default. If you want to persist files between `job`s, use the `publish` and `download` tasks. Refer to the documentation for more details.

Comment: When I ran the script in the same job, I had the same problem. :(